# Bind NameValueCollection toTextBlock

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have `ItemsControl`which use template to bind data.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"  x:Name="MyCollectionControl" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyCollectionTemplate}" />
```

**MyCollection** is type of `NameValueCollection` and The following binding does not work. It is populating correct number of pairs but `TextBlock` does not get the bounded value.

**Template**

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="MyCollectionTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <TextBox Name="CValue"/>
        </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

**mainWindow**

```
string[] dataCollection=new string[5];
....
....
Student studentObject=new Student("1",dataCollection);

this.dataContext = studentObject;
```

**Student Class**

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id;
    public NameValueCollection MyCollection {get; set;}    

    public Student(string id, params string[] additionalInfo)
    {
        Id =  id;       

        if (additionalInfo != null)
        {
            MyCollection=new NameValueCollection();

            foreach (string s in MyCollection)
            {
                string[] tokens = s.Split('|');
                if (tokens.Length == 2)
                    MyCollection.Add(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

What is the wrong I am doing when binding `NameValueCollection`.

Please advice me.

Comment: Can you show code behind for what MyCollection is and how it gets populated?

Comment: How are you converting your string array to a `NameValueCollection` ?  Also is that main window code in the constructor or elsewhere?

Comment: It is in the constructor. Have I made a mistake when passing value to `NameValueCollection `? Please correct me.

Comment: Well it is unclear how you get from sending a string array when creating the student object to a NameValueCollection you are trying to bind to.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia- i have added the `Student` Constructor. I think now it gives you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK a couple of things, one you probably want to change your DataTemplate a bit since you are overlaying a textbox directly over your textblock, for my test I just changed it to a stack panel:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    <TextBox Name="CValue"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Also notice I changed to simply `Text="{Binding}"` since the items within the NameValueCollection are simply strings and don't have a value attribute.

Also not sure if this was just another typo, but this:

```
foreach (string s in MyCollection)
{
    string[] tokens = s.Split('|');
    if (tokens.Length == 2)
        MyCollection.Add(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
}
```

should probably say:

```
foreach (string s in additionalInfo)
{
    string[] tokens = s.Split('|');
    if (tokens.Length == 2)
        MyCollection.Add(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
}
```

otherwise you are just iterating over an empty collection.

Comment: Ok wow, Its is working. But I have an issue. for the textblock it is binding **name**. If I want to bind value to the **TextBox** What should I do?

Comment: @NewDeveloper There doesn't seem to be an easy way to get to the values as a flat list using this kind of collection (I'd never actually heard of it until reading this question, so my apologies).  Is there any reason you can't just use a `Dictionary` ?

Comment: Since it is name value pair, I choose this. If it is that much difficult, I will think of having alternative. Thanks for the all the help you did. Your answer help me in to some extend. Thanks again.